# Value changing when converting from double to int

Tags: c++, int, double

Basic question, the code is very large, but my issue is, at it's core, basic :

I have a double value known as variable, and if I check it with cout << variable, it will give me, for example, 982.

The very next line of code is int intvariable = variable.

Then, when I check it with cout << intvariable, I'm given 981.

The funny thing is, this doesn't always happen. With 985 it might stay at 985, but then at 984 and 983, it will return 983 and 982. I can't seem to figure this out at ALL. I've tried converting it to a float and then to an int, or to another double and then an int.

I need it as an int so I can use the modulus operator with it.

I should point out, previously in the code the double is less than 1 (i.e, 0.987), and is then multiplied by the number of decimal places to make it a real, positive integer (though, it's stored as a double still at that point). Maybe that has something to do with the random rounding?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: I've seen that page before, and I understand floating points, but I'm still at a loss. Why is it that when I'm asking to see the number (while it's still a double) with cout, it's giving me -exactly- the number I expect to see, but upon viewing it as an int, it's different. I'm not doing any math in between.

Comment: As you mention in your question, your problem is rounding.  I don't know why you say "random rounding", though.

Comment: Printing with `cout` *formats* your number. Be sure to understand what that means.

Comment: Floating point problems often result in something like "5" not really being "5", but being "5.00000008" or something. Which can be trouble if you're being exact. In MY case, I have a double, with a value of, say, 955, but when I convert it to an int, it loses an entire 1's place value, and drops to 954. You -can- represent every non-decimal number as an integer, so why can't my program seem to comprehend 955 = 955? It shouldn't be taking the floating point (say as a double, 955 is really 954.99999997, or something), and making it 954 as an int.

Comment: @JerryMacPherson, it sounds like you don't fully understand the internal representation used by IEEE754 floating point numbers.  Check out the link I posted above.

Comment: The other answer was great, but thanks for all the help given. I found I could use the ceil(); function (which could probably end up increasing the value by one), but the other poster gave the option of simply adding 0.5 before casting, which is probably safer. Thanks for everyones time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting a floating point value to an `int` will truncate (return the floor of) the value, possibly leading to your problems because floating point numbers are inherently imprecise. Try rounding the number instead, i.e. `intvariable =  (int)(0.5 + variable)`. You might also be interested in the `fmod` function, which computes the remainder of floating point division (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/).

Comment: Ah, interesting... so just chuck some extra onto the number to make sure it's sitting under the right value. I like this answer. I actually found a solution just now by using the ceil(); function, which is pretty much this same thing. Thanks for understanding the problem and addressing it swiftly! I know this answer might not be the best in every situation, but for my program this is absolutely what I need.